# Form View page redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

I am using a `FormView` to display data with a `SqlDataSource` and my platform is MSVS2013.

Lets say I have 4 data in Data table so it displays fist data set with page numbers at the bottom.

But if I select 2nd or 3rd on any other page number then it will refresh the page and set proper data in the `FormView`. The problem is if I select any other page number it will change data and not navigate view back to same position to the page, instead it shows the top position of the page.

Can any one help Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use update panel... it will give the solution